# QGIS GDAL Build VRT results do not reflect input raster values

Tags: qgis, raster, gdal, vrt

I am having trouble successfully creating a VRT.

My Build VRT gdal command results in values of ±1.79769e+308. The values should be 1,2,3, or 4.

I've verified projection info is the same across the input rasters.

Input rasters (.tifs) are:

- FLT4S (also tried INT1U)
- LZW compressed
- 1 m pixel size

There are large nodata spaces in between the rasters, but setting no data to -9999, does not change results.

±1.79769e+308 is strangely the range of values for 32 bit floating data types, (FLT8S).

Is this a clue?

I am using QGIS 3.4.14 on Mac

When I use a different set of input rasters GDAL VRT works fine. So I think it has something to do with the input raster types, rather than GDAL or QGIS.

This is the GDAL command:

```
gdalbuildvrt -resolution highest -r nearest -input_file_list /private/var/vw/buildvrtInputFiles.txt /Users/forVRT/vrt.vrt
```

Comment: It feels like some issue with nodata. What nodata does your input images use? Could it be NaN or -NaN? Show your whole gdalubuildvrt command.

Comment: Added the gdal command. I  tried both NaN and -NaN. This results in vrt min/max value of 0, a definite change from ±1.79769e+308, but still not the expected result. I also tried -9999 as a nodata value, same result.

Comment: The nodata of the source files is important as well and if it is same for all the images. In the command above, having spaces after commas may also cause trouble.

Comment: Just an update: I checked and reset when necessary nodata values to all be the same. I double-checked projection and spatial resolution but still have not been able to get a vrt made. There is still some difference in the rasters that is causing the error. Based on the raster properties I can access, I can't see any differences (besides spatial extent).